# Angular2-Leafletjs: Defining style for L.geoJSON().addTo(myMap)

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, geojson

In am using **[Leafletjs in Angular2](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/angular2-leaflet)**, `http.get` to invoke JSON from a URL, but I can't define style for the features that are added to the map because of predefining the geoJSON layer:

```
  // Add an empty layer to the map
  var geoJsonLayer1 = L.geoJSON().addTo(myMap);

  // Retrieve the geojson file
  http.get(myJsonURL)
  .map((response: Response) => {
      geoJsonLayer1.addData(response.json());
  }).subscribe();
```

The geoJSON layer doesn't have any style and it looks as below:

[image]

The reason that I am predefining the layer is, I am lazy-loading the JSON file. In the regular way, we can define the style as below:

```
L.geoJSON(myLines, {
    style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);
```

Now my question is, how to define the style for a predefined layer?

Answer (score 0):

Just predefine the layer without data…

```
var geoJsonLayer1 = L.geoJSON(null, {
  style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);

// Later on…
geoJsonLayer1.addData(response.json());
```

BTW your screenshot looks to show markers (for `"Point"` type features) with missing icon image. In that case, instead of `style` option for vector shapes (like polygons, line strings, etc.), you should use the [`pointToLayer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#geojson-pointtolayer) option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to define a null layer and specify the style, but unfortunately it didn't work this way in Angular2. Regarding the pointToLayer, in this particular example, the dataset was point but it could be polygon or a polyline.

Comment: I do not see how Angular would change Leaflet behaviour. If you can provide an MCVE and ideally a live example that reproduces your issue, it would be possible to see what is wrong, otherwise I am afraid there is little that can be done further.

Comment: I have made the repo on github: https://github.com/gharibi/Angular2-Leaflet. Here you can see the code. Under src/app/app.components.ts, in line # 100, when you predefine the layer for lazyloading it, you will face with this issue.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I am not going to go through your entire code.